# Function or functor calling using sprit boost parser library rule to save values in vector c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I want to parse this line and storing all hex values in functor
**<005F> <0061> [<00660066> <00660069> <00660066006C>]**
this values in txt file and m reading this fill line by line

like 
005F 0061 00660066 00660069 00660066006C
all values should be in vector but its not working

the spirit rule is to parse this line is

```
rule<> blanks = *blank_p;
rule<> parse_int = blanks >> "<" >> int_p [AddEntry] >> ">";
rule<> parse_ints = *parse_int ;
rule<> parse_range = *parse_int >>"[" >> blanks >> *parse_int >> "]";

int status = parse (line.c_str(),
*(
     parse_range 
 )
 ).full;
```

and my functor is this

```
struct AddEntry
{
    vector<int> list;   
    void operator()( int integer)
    {
        list.push_back(integer);
    }
};
```

Comment: Time to use Spirit V2? Classical has been obsolete for many many years

Comment: how can i achieve it using V2?
any example related that will be appreciated ?

Comment: pleas check it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f96cf74663cc86
why both parsing functions are true i want the simple function be false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample doing this using Spirit V2

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70688b13f7455cf4)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi  = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    std::string const line = "<005F> <0061> [<00660066> <00660069> <00660066006C>]";

    It f = line.begin(), l = line.end();

    qi::int_parser<uintmax_t, 16> hex_int;
    qi::rule<It, uintmax_t()> braced_hex = '<' >> hex_int >> '>';
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(braced_hex);

    std::vector<uintmax_t> list;
    bool result = qi::phrase_parse(f, l, *braced_hex >> '[' >> *braced_hex >> ']', qi::space, list);

    if (result) {
        std::cout << "Parse success: " << list.size() << "\n";

        for (auto& v : list)
            std::cout << v << " ";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parse success: 5
95 97 6684774 6684777 438093348972
```

Debug output (if enabled):

```
<braced_hex>
    <try><005F> <0061> [<0066</try>
    <success> <0061> [<00660066> </success>
    <attributes>[95]</attributes>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try><0061> [<00660066> <</try>
    <success> [<00660066> <006600</success>
    <attributes>[97]</attributes>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try>[<00660066> <0066006</try>
    <fail/>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try><00660066> <00660069</try>
    <success> <00660069> <0066006</success>
    <attributes>[6684774]</attributes>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try><00660069> <00660066</try>
    <success> <00660066006C>]</success>
    <attributes>[6684777]</attributes>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try><00660066006C>]</try>
    <success>]</success>
    <attributes>[438093348972]</attributes>
</braced_hex>
<braced_hex>
    <try>]</try>
    <fail/>
</braced_hex>
```

Note that on my system `int` wasn't big enough to hold those numbers, so parse would fail. For maximum range I used `intmax_t` but you can use other types, including arbitrary precision types:

- **[128 bit string to array using boost::spirit::*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073725/128-bit-string-to-array-using-boostspirit/28076256#28076256)**

Also note I prefer not to use semantic actions, using automatic attribute propagation. This is really prevalent in Spirit V2. See also

- [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

Comment: Thank you very much sehe i am learning it and thanks for help :)

Comment: there is a lil error while debugging do u know this ?

Comment: 1>parseer.cpp(21): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before ':'
1>parseer.cpp(21): error C2530: 'v' : references must be initialized
1>parseer.cpp(21): error C3531: 'v': a symbol whose type contains 'auto' must have an initializer
1>
1>Build FAILED.

Comment: Seems your compiler doesn't support c++11 (fully). Change it to c++03: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/04561beae116a979)**

Comment: pleas check it http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8f96cf74663cc86 why both parsing functions are true i want the simple function be false

Comment: sorry check this one 
[link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b8c35a967de4a609)
*other question is when i change the order of both check1 and check2 i got different values :( kindly help me out...